# Ajax pass two parameter

Tags: ajax

This is my ajax code to pass two variables to php file.

```
var developer = $('#developerSelect').val();
      var level = $('#userLevelSelect').val();
      console.log(developer);
      console.log(level);

     $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-GenerateUserbyLevelReport.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {developerSelected : developer,userlevel : level },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){
              console.log(response);
            }

          })
```

I pass two variable to php file with the syntax like this : -

> data: {developerSelected : developer,userlevel : level },

ajax-GenerateUserbyLevelReport.php :-

```
    <?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $developer = $_POST['developerSelected'];
    $userLevel = $_POST['userlevel'];

    // this query is to get the developer id 
$DevQuery="SELECT id AS `ID` FROM pams_developer WHERE developer_name=:name";
$Dev_ID = ($GetReport->GetID($DevQuery,$developer));

//this query is the get all the user level id 
$UserLevelQuery="SELECT id AS `ID` FROM pams_user_levels WHERE description=:name";
$Level_ID = ($GetReport->GetID($UserLevelQuery,$userLevel));


    $UserLevelQuery = "SELECT `pams_users`.display_name AS Name ,`pams_user_levels`.description,`pams_users`.datecreated AS DateCreated,last_date AS LastLogin FROM pams_users 
    JOIN pams_developer ON `pams_users`.developer_id=`pams_developer`.id AND `pams_developer`.id=:dev_id 
    JOIN pams_user_levels ON `pams_user_levels`.id=`pams_users`.user_level AND `pams_user_levels`.id=$Level_ID
    ORDER BY `pams_user_levels`.description ASC";
    $UserbyUserLevel= $GetReport->GetData($UserLevelQuery,$Dev_ID);
    echo json_encode($UserbyUserLevel,JSON_HEX_APOS);
        //json_encode data echo here
        ?>
```

But the problem is the console.log(response) return nothing.
Anyone can help me figure out my problem ?

Comment: Add error property to see what happened: `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  alert(xhr.responseText);
}`

Comment: yea , i added  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("some error");
     }

Comment: and the error message is shown

Comment: @WeiKang In the error function do alert("Error thrown::"+errorThrown) and let us know of the error message displayed

Comment: @Tej , the message shown Error thrown::SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0

Comment: @WeiKang Also take a look at the dataType you are setting for request, it is json and the return values in php should be echo json_encode(array($developer, $userLevel));

Comment: @WeiKang In JS file do console.log($.parseJSON(response)[0]) and console.log($.parseJSON(response)[1]) separately to get values back

Comment: @Tej Thanks for your comment. But i just edit my php file. can u help me chekc it ? Still cannot get the response.

Comment: @WeiKang Without posting what is the exception you are getting I or anyone on the site will not be able to help you on this site.

Comment: @Tej. Yea.. I just figure it out already because I have html code in the php file that i want to send json_encode data.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl for debug, for example

`Curl -v -X POST 'http://server/server.script.php' -d '{"developerSelected":"Jhon","user level":"24"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Your dataType is set to `json`, but your data is not in json format,so just remove the dataType and it will work

```
   $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-GenerateUserbyLevelReport.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {developerSelected : developer,userlevel : level },
            //dataType: 'json', // just remove this line
            success:function(response){
              console.log(response);
            }

   });
```

If you still want to use `json`, then you need to use `JSON.stringify()` to change your data parameter:

```
   var dataObj = {developerSelected : developer,userlevel : level };
   $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-GenerateUserbyLevelReport.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
            dataType: 'json', 
            success:function(response){
              console.log(response);
            }

   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i just edit my php file. can u help me chekc it ? Still cannot get the response.